# using a smart pointer in C

Tags: c

I was given the task to implement the following `C` function, which implements a `C vector`:

```
 40 CVector *CVectorCreate(int elemSize, int capacityHint, CVectorCleanupElemFn fn)
 41 {
 42     //allocate a new CVector struct
 43     CVector *cvector = (CVector*)calloc(1, sizeof(CVector));
 44     assert(cvector != NULL);
 45     //allocate space for the buffer
 46     cvector->vector = calloc(capacityHint, elemSize);
 47     assert(cvector->vector != NULL);
 48     /*
 49      * Use these in other to make the code more efficient
 50      * and also there is going to have less coding in other to
 51      * perform the same operation
 52      * I'm also going to explicity initialize all the members of
 53      * vector even though I don't need
 54      */
 55     cvector->capacity = capacityHint;
 56     cvector->elemSize = elemSize;
 57     cvector->head = cvector->tail = 0;
 58     return cvector;
 59 }
```

I also defined `CVector` as the following struct:

```
 17 typedef struct CVectorImplementation {
 18     // include your desired fields here
 19     int head;
 20     int tail;
 21     int numElements;
 22     int capacity;
 23     int elemSize;
 24     void* vector;
 25 }CVector;
```

However, in the head of the function `CVectorCreate`, there is the `CVectorCleanupElemFn` which I would imagine that is for the use of a smart pointer, but I'm not sure how to include/use that function into my struct. May someone with more experience please tell me what's the purpose of `CVectorCleanupElemFn` and how could I use it?
I also have the following function(Timo's suggestion put in place):

```
 63 void CVectorDispose(CVector *cv)
 64 {
 65     assert(cv != NULL);
 66     // I would imagine cleanUp holds the function
 67     // that empties the buffer
 68     int index = cv->head;
 69     while(index <= tail) {
 70         (cv->cleanupFn)(cv->vector[index]);
            ++index;
 71     }
 72     free(cv->vector);
 73     // finally free the struct cv
 74     free(cv);
 75 }
```

I'm trying to figure out how to bind them together.

Comment: You are using `assert` incorrectly.  It is not logically impossible for calloc to return NULL.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: that's not true. If the memory manager fails to find and allocate requested memory block, it returns `NULL`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I didn't know it was logically impossible for `calloc` return NULL. Then, as a good practice, you always include the error handler, even though you may not need

Comment: William said "not impossible", not "not possible".

Comment: @WilliamPursell `assert()` aborts upon encountering a false condition, i. e. here when allocation fails.

Comment: @Jack.  Your second point is correct, but you misread my statement.  Calloc may return NULL.  Hence, it is not logically impossible for calloc to return NULL.  So the assertion is invalid.

Comment: `assert` is a no-op if compiled with NDEBUG.  This is the canonically incorrect usage.  `assert` is *not* for error checking.

Comment: Wow, @WilliamPursell, that double negative tripped me up and probably others too.  To reiterate: `calloc` can return null.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood correctly the cleanup function is used for cleaning up invidual elements in the vector. (In C++ terms it would be the destructor for the element type.) So when ever you remove an element from the vector the cleanup function should be called for the element. It's probably defined something like this:

```
typedef void (*CVectorCleanupElemFn)(void*);
```

So you would just store the function pointer in your struct

```
typedef struct CVectorImplementation {
    // include your desired fields here
     int head;
     int tail;
     int numElements;
     int capacity;
     int elemSize;
     void* vector;
     CVectorCleanupElemFn cleanupFn;
} CVector;
```

And you would call it like this:

```
(*cvector->cleanupFn)(pointerToTheElement)
```

edit:
In the CVectorDispose function the idea is correct but it's a bit buggy. You're storing a void pointer to the buffer so you need to convert it to `char*` to do arithmetic with it. And you need to take account the element size:

```
(*cv->cleanupFn)((char*)cv->vector + index * cv->elemSize);
```

and your loop is one element too long, if tail is the index one past the last element. Should be

```
while(index < tail)
```

Comment: Timo, so the cleanupFn only removes one element of the array at each time?

Comment: I also updated my question to add the `CVectorDispose()` function